# Icons DPI for Android

Tags: android, icons, resolution, dpi, android-screen-support

I apologize for the simple question, but I am a bit confused.

I am creating my first Android app. Functinally I am done. I am now working on the UI. According to [this](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html), I am required to provide multiple icons to support different screens and I understand this part.

So I created a vector image, and was about to export it to generate a number of icons to support multiple resolutions. However, I could not find the require DPI. According to [this](http://www.tivix.com/blog/perfect-resource-image-size-dpi-for-any-android-device/), I am supposed to support different DPIs, but the article does not explain how to do that.

Can you please advise me on how to select the proper DPI? Does it even matter? I thought it does, but maybe my understanding is wrong.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify my question. When I am exporting an image from a vector to a raster image, I have to select its dimension (so in my case, 400px X 200px), and its dpi. So what should I choose for DPI? Is that the same DPI that will create different icon sizes? I am confused. Thanks again.

Comment: I would suggest you to consider the size of `ic_launcher.png` which is the launcher icon as a reference and design your icons on the basis of that..Not sure if it is the best answer...

Comment: read the section that begins "So, to create an icon for different densities, you should follow the 2:3:4:6:8 scaling ratio..." on http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: What icons are we talking about? Launcher? ActionBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing my conclusion for the greater good. After further reading and investigation. It appears that DPI is not important when I am creating an image for a screen. So when I choose 400px X 200px, and assuming this will be for mdpi, then I should choose 800px X 400px for xdpi (and so on and so forth). The dpi should be ignored in all cases (does not matter if I chloose dpi of 90 or 600, as long as this is not for printing). On the other hand, if I am to print the image, then dpi is important.

---

**EDIT**

[This](http://webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi) is a great article about the topic. Please read it, it explains things very well.

Comment: If you think so, you can make this experiment:  
for an **xhdpi** screen, prepare a 800px X 400px image at **72 dpi** (`and no other images for other resolutions`) and see how does it scale down in a lower resolution physical device, say an ldpi screen (it will look really **bad**)...  
Then prepare a 800px X 400px image at **480 dpi** (`and no other images for other resolutions`) and, after scaling (will look very **good**, on the same ldpi screen),  compare the result to the previous one.

The difference will be evident on a physical device, much less on an emulator.

Comment: Great idea. I will try it. Maybe in a couple of weeks though. Just have to finish this. If it works, I will remove this answer and accept yours again, and add a comment about the results of this experiment. Thanks.

Comment: It's a way of doing things when you want to save some bytes on lower resolutions pictures: just prepare the highest resolution ones and let Android scale them down (it will scale down the ones it doesn't find in their folders).

Comment: I am adding this comment. I do not think I will do this experiment. Here is a great article about this topic: webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi and after reading the article, it seems that my conclusion was correct about DPI.

Comment: That article mostly talks about **monitors**, not mobile devices. And most monitors today use 72 or 96 dpi. So, for **monitors**, 72 dpi is appropriate. I'll **never** provide such a **low quality** graphics to my mobile apps!

Comment: A monitor or a mobile device are the same. It is a screen. Assume an image is 100 px X 100 px. Now on a device such as modern an iPhone or Android, this image will appear small. On a monitor, with low resolution, this image will appear large. It does not matter what the DPI is. It does not even make sense. DPI (or dots per inch), are used for print, where you can fit that many dots in one inch. Now if your device is 480dpi, the image will be on a certain size. However, a 160dpi device will make it appear larger.

Comment: Maybe you are like me before reaching my conclusion. I was confused between PX, DP and DPI. I did not have much understanding, But reading this article (and others), made me distinguish clearly between them.

Comment: Reading that article confirmed my theory, for me.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your input in any case.

Answer (score 1):

For what concerns **dpi**, I use to follow the screen dpi:

**640** dpi for **xxxhdpi** screens
**480** dpi for **xxhdpi** screens
**320** dpi for **xhdpi** screens
**240** dpi for **hdpi** screens
**160** dpi for **mdpi** screens
**120** dpi for **ldpi** screens

This way I'm sure the icons are appropriate to the screen resolution.

I'm also sure that I can skip some (if not all) the lower qualities, once I have the **highest** resolution graphics, because they will scale **down** nearly perfectly.

But, since I'm a perfectionist, **nearly** disturbs me.
So, I do provide all the resolutions graphics.

---

For what concerns **dimensions** use this cheatsheet: http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#dimensions

---

You can make this experiment:
for an **xhdpi** screen, prepare a 800px X 400px image at **72 dpi** (`and no other images for other resolutions`) and see how does it scale down in a lower resolution physical device, say an ldpi screen (it will look really **bad**)...
Then prepare a 800px X 400px image at **480 dpi** (`and no other images for other resolutions`) and, after scaling (will look very **good**, on the same ldpi screen),  compare the result to the previous one.

The difference will be evident on a physical device, much less on an emulator.

It's a way of doing things when you want to save some bytes on lower resolution pictures: just prepare the highest resolutions ones and let Android scale them down (it will scale down the ones it doesn't find in their folders).